# What's the difference between "Speakers of English" and "English speakers"?

Tags: differences, noun-phrases

What's the difference between "Speakers of English" and "English speakers"?

Comment: There isn't really any difference in meaning. Sometimes for phonetic reasons *of* phrases will sound better than their alternatives, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Speakers of English are people who speak English (the language). On the other hand, English speakers may be confused with speakers from England ( the country).

Comment: Ah!! Thanks a lot that's more like it. it makes sense now :)

Comment: While "English speakers" *could* be confused, it will almost always be essentially synonymous. I can't think of an example where I would want to distinguish between two nationalities and would use the word *speakers*. I think this answer is wrong to suggest this confusion.

Comment: I agree. If one wants to distinguish, one can say, e.g., British English (BrE) speaker, or American English (AmE) speaker. This refers to the language itself, but there's a strong likelihood that they will be of that nationality as well, and a certainty if you peface with "native".

Comment: After reading this many times I came to the conclusion Babe meant something like "At the conference, the stage was first taken by the English speakers and later speakers from China"

Comment: @mplungjan Well done for finding one of the few cases where it would make sense. That's acceptable but only because it's completely clear from context that "speakers" is short for "conference speakers". The "speakers from England" that Babel refers to is another thing completely.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I think that is exactly what Babel meant, otherwise the second part of his answer does not make any sense to me, the _non-native English speaker_

Answer (score 1):

In most situations, *speakers of English* and *English speakers* would be taken to mean the same thing, namely 'people who speak English'.

The main exception I can think of is a context that focuses on geographically-based differences in the speech patterns of people who speak English.

For instance, someone might say:

> Americans often say *"I'm good"* when someone greets them with "How are you?" **English speakers,** on the other hand, are more likely to reply to that greeting with *"I'm fine".*

Here, even though the person making the statement has not *explicitly* said what they mean by the term 'English speakers', it is clear that a common locution in the speech of American speakers of English is being contrasted with a corresponding locution that is more typical of **speakers of English who also come from England**.